# Dependencies on Stored proc

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have a situation where i cannot update SSRS report but i have permissions to updte Stored Procedure assoicated with that report..After updating Stored Procedure i thought what  if some report uses same Stored Procedure..I tried to find dependencies on Stored Procedure but couldnt find number of SSRS reports depend on that Stored Proc..so
Just want to know Is there any way  can i  find number of  **SSRS reports** depend on one **Stored Procedure?**

Thanks,
sree.k

Answer (score 1):

If you cant search a project/solution (visual studio?) for the specific sp,
If you have (read) access to the ReportServer database you can just run a script searching for your SP.

For the guts of the query - thanks to http://bretstateham.com/extracting-ssrs-report-rdl-xml-from-the-reportserver-database/, then its simply a matter of searching for a string in the xml that is returned.  (the string you're searching for is on the last line

```
--The first CTE gets the content as a varbinary(max)
--as well as the other important columns for all reports,
--data sources and shared datasets.
WITH ItemContentBinaries AS
(
  SELECT
    ItemID,Name,[Type]
    ,CASE Type
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Report'
       WHEN 5 THEN 'Data Source'
       WHEN 7 THEN 'Report Part'
       WHEN 8 THEN 'Shared Dataset'
       ELSE 'Other'
     END AS TypeDescription
    ,CONVERT(varbinary(max),Content) AS Content
    ,Path
  FROM ReportServer.dbo.Catalog
  WHERE Type IN (2,5,7,8)
),
--The second CTE strips off the BOM if it exists...
ItemContentNoBOM AS
(
  SELECT
     ItemID,Name,[Type],TypeDescription
    ,CASE
       WHEN LEFT(Content,3) = 0xEFBBBF
         THEN CONVERT(varbinary(max),SUBSTRING(Content,4,LEN(Content)))
       ELSE
         Content
     END AS Content
     ,path
  FROM ItemContentBinaries
)
--The outer query gets the content in its varbinary, varchar and xml representations...
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT
   ItemID,Path,Name,[Type],TypeDescription
  ,Content --varbinary
  ,CONVERT(varchar(max),Content) AS ContentVarchar --varchar
  ,CONVERT(xml,Content) AS ContentXML --xml
FROM ItemContentNoBOM
)_x
WHERE charindex('dbo.ReportProcToSearchFor',cast([_x].ContentXML as nvarchar(max))) > 0
```